# http url error when it contains number?

Tags: java, http, retrofit

I am using retrofit in Java to send http Request,

The url I send like "account/32/Factivation/34"

my retrofit function like this:

```
@PUT("/tpd/{activeurl}")
Observable<Result<OTPVerificationResponse>> rxputActivation(
        @Path("activeurl") String url
);
```

When I debug , I found, the actual url I send is like

```
"account%2F34%2Factivation%2F37"
```

So I guess there is an error when pass "account/32/Factivation/34" to retrofit ?

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Path.html):

> Values are URL encoded by default. Disable with `encoded=true`.